# ¿Diferencia entre clases de tipo Any y T en Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

En Kotlin me he topado con diversos fragmentos de código en donde hacen uso de clases Any y/o genéricas(T), en donde el objetivo es indicar que esa variable puede ser de cualquier clase.

Según la documentación oficial Any es la superclase en kotlin, todas las clases heredan de ella.

Mis dudas son:
¿Cual es la diferencia entre ambos tipos de clases?
¿Cuando y donde usar cada una?

Comment: Cuando dices T, te refieres a un tipo generico?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo concreto?

Answer (score 3):

No tengo experiencia con Kotlin, pero tras leer la documentación `Any` es la superclase raiz de todas (equivalente a `object` en C# por ejemplo). Todo objeto hereda de `Any`, por tanto todo objeto es de tipo `Any`.

Los tipos genéricos son otra cosa. `T` es sustituido en cada caso por el tipo del objeto que se pasa al método, pero no existe `boxing` ni `unboxing`. Puedes pensar en ello como un *comodín* que es sustituido por el tipo correspondiente, y cualquier en el paso de una variable a otra de tipo `T`, se comprueba que coincidan ambos tipos.

En cuanto a cuando usar cada una, lo normal es utilizar siempre donde sea posible los genéricos. De esa manera te ahorraras por un lado tener que realizar en algún momento un *cast* al tipo correcto, y por el otro el compilador te avisará en tiempo de compilación de cualquier error de *casting* que tengas en tu código.

Como digo no tengo experiencia con Kotlin, pero su filosofía es por lo que veo prácticamente calcada a la de .Net. Y basándome en eso, yo diría que usar `Any` no es apropiado prácticamente en ningún contexto, ya que pierdes todas las ventajas del tipado de objetos. Usa siempre genéricos.

Comment: Tomo la explicación de las clases genericas, sin embargo creo que la clase Any se puede manejar con algunas ventajas.

Comment: Como te digo @dámazoD ,no conozco Koitlin. Pero he leido un poco de la documentación y como digo es simplemente la clase raiz de todas las demas clases. Puedes usar `Any` cuando no te importa el tipo del objeto (por ejemplo, si quieres imprimir todos los objetos de una colección, podrías usar Any ya que todos tienen el método `toString`. Pero mas allá de eso, lo normal debe ser usar `T` o `*` que mantienen el tipo durante todo el método. De todas maneras, a lo mejor alguien mas experto puede darte una mejor respuesta.